# Delphi Copy-on-Write for String

Tags: string, delphi

I have a code like this:

```
function Test: string;
var
   r, s: string;
begin
   r := 'Hello';
   Writeln(NativeInt(PChar(@r[1])));
   s := r;
   Writeln(NativeInt(PChar(@s[1])));
   Result := r;
   Writeln(NativeInt(PChar(@Result[1])));
end;
```

People say that delphi uses copy-on-write for strings. but the above function prints 3 different Addresses for variable, r, s, and Result. So this is confusing.. Is there only a copy of 'Hello' string in memory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever you take the address of an element of a string, that counts as a *write* in the eyes of the compiler. As far as it is concerned, you now have a raw pointer to the internals of the string, and who knows what you plan to do with it. So, from its perspective, it plays safe. It decides to make a unique copy of the string, so that you are free to do whatever dastardly deed you plan to do with your raw pointer.

The code you have compiles to this:

```
Project2.dpr.13: r := 'Hello';
00419EF8 8D45FC           lea eax,[ebp-$04]
00419EFB BAA89F4100       mov edx,$00419fa8
00419F00 E827D2FEFF       call @UStrLAsg
Project2.dpr.14: Writeln(NativeInt(PChar(@r[1])));
00419F05 8D45FC           lea eax,[ebp-$04]
00419F08 E883D3FEFF       call @UniqueStringU
00419F0D 8BD0             mov edx,eax
00419F0F A18CE64100       mov eax,[$0041e68c]
00419F14 E853B2FEFF       call @Write0Long
00419F19 E82EB5FEFF       call @WriteLn
00419F1E E845A1FEFF       call @_IOTest
Project2.dpr.15: s := r;
00419F23 8D45F8           lea eax,[ebp-$08]
00419F26 8B55FC           mov edx,[ebp-$04]
00419F29 E8FED1FEFF       call @UStrLAsg
Project2.dpr.16: Writeln(NativeInt(PChar(@s[1])));
00419F2E 8D45F8           lea eax,[ebp-$08]
00419F31 E85AD3FEFF       call @UniqueStringU
00419F36 8BD0             mov edx,eax
00419F38 A18CE64100       mov eax,[$0041e68c]
00419F3D E82AB2FEFF       call @Write0Long
00419F42 E805B5FEFF       call @WriteLn
00419F47 E81CA1FEFF       call @_IOTest
Project2.dpr.17: Result := r;
00419F4C 8BC3             mov eax,ebx
00419F4E 8B55FC           mov edx,[ebp-$04]
00419F51 E88ED1FEFF       call @UStrAsg
Project2.dpr.18: Writeln(NativeInt(PChar(@Result[1])));
00419F56 8BC3             mov eax,ebx
00419F58 E833D3FEFF       call @UniqueStringU
00419F5D 8BD0             mov edx,eax
00419F5F A18CE64100       mov eax,[$0041e68c]
00419F64 E803B2FEFF       call @Write0Long
00419F69 E8DEB4FEFF       call @WriteLn
00419F6E E8F5A0FEFF       call @_IOTest
```

The calls to `UniqueStringU` are performing the copy in copy-on-write.

Comment: so the UniqueStringU  will copy the content of the string ? so there will be 3 copies of 'Hello' in memory, am I correct?

Comment: Actually there will be 4. The constant one in read only memory, and the three copies.

Comment: just to be clear, if I removed the 3 writeln statements in the example code, just  s:=r; result:=r;  will there be only 1 copy of the string?

Comment: Correct. Or if you replaced `PChar(@r[1])` with `PChar(r)` which is actually the more usual cast since it is guaranteed to be null terminated

Comment: @David While you are correct in the mechanics, what is actually happening is a little more subtle. The compiler doesn't merely assume that by indexing it is to create a unique string. In the above case, it is taking the address of the element is what causes this.

Comment: @Allen That was sloppy in my writing. It's clearly the fact that the address is taken that matters. I'll fix.

Comment: PChar( S ) will do a unique, Pointer( S ) will not!

Comment: @RitsaertHornstra I don't believe that is accurate

Comment: @RitsaertHornstra: I know that is inaccurate. I just tested it. `PChar` causes the call of `@UStrToPWChar`, but that finally points to the same address, if the string is not empty. `Pointer` avoids that call, so there you could get a `nil`.